# How to change the default OrderBy functionality so that it orders by a given value first?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a set of results coming back from a Linq to SQL query. Each result has a `Name` and a `SeriesId`. The `SeriesId` can be any value from 1 to N,

So the results might initially come out of the database like this (i.e. any order):

```
FundA1
FundA6
FundA4
FundC6
FundC3
FundC4
FundB2
FundB7
FundB8
FundB6
```

I need to get these ordered first by `Name`, and then by `SeriesId` *but* I need to show `SeriesId == 6` first, then the rest in any order.

So for example, I need

```
**FundA6**
FundA1
FundA4
**FundB6**
FundB2
FundB7
FundB8
**FundC6**
FundC3
FundC4
```

I know it's possible for me to order by `Name` and then `SeriesId` by doing this:

```
return queryable.OrderBy(f => f.Name).ThenBy(s => s.SeriesId));
```

but this will order the `SeriesId` by the lowest value first. Is there a way for me to override this default functionality by specifying that it should order by `SeriesId` starting at 6 rather than 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
return queryable.OrderBy(f => f.Name)
                .ThenBy(f => f.SeriesId == 6 ? 0 : 1)
                .ThenBy(s => s.SeriesId));
```

That relies on "false" ordering earlier than "true" - I *think* it will work... it would in LINQ to Objects, at least.

Comment: Do you think it would be cleaner to do something explicit, such as `ThenBy(f => f.SeriedId == 6 ? 0 : 1)` (assuming it translates to efficient SQL) rather than relying upon someone understanding the ordering of true and false?

Answer (score 3):

```
return queryable
    .OrderBy(f => f.Name)
    .ThenBy(f => f.SerialId == 6)
    .ThenBy(f => f.SeriesId);
```

Comment: That was what I thought at first, but I believe the "series 6 first" ordering still only comes *after* the name, given the sample data. Also, I believe that will put series 6 at the *end* as false is ordered before true. I think. Maybe. On a Friday.

Comment: hmmm, I'll try a test locally

Comment: Hmm... I've just tried it in LINQ to Objects and I'm getting the values corresponding to SeriesId 6 at the *end*.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own comparer, and give it as a second parameter to OrderBy, ot ThenBy.
The way user OrderBy, you rely on default comparer, that compares strings normally. But you can create your own, that will always return "6" first.
PS. Yes this won`t work directly on LINQ2SQL. But, since, you are loading all the values anyway. You can first load them, and then sort in memory.

Here`s an example:

```
class Sample
{
    string[] strings = new[]{ "123","123456", "12345"};

    public void SampleMethod()
    {
        var res = strings.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(s => s.Length, new MyComparer());
    }

    class MyComparer : IComparer<int>
    {
        public int Compare(int x, int y)
        {
            if (x == 6) return -1;
            return x - y;
        }
    }
}
```

.AsEnumerable() is needed in order for LINQ2SQL to load the data into memory.

Comment: I don't believe you can specify custom comparers in LINQ to SQL.

Comment: This won`t work if you want to use it for filtering. But for sorting: just load all the values and sort in memory

Comment: It would probably be worth saying how to do that then (e.g. using AsEnumerable).

Comment: Your comparer implementation is broken, since `x - y` could overflow. (For example, `int.MinValue < int.MaxValue == true`, but `int.MinValue - int.MaxValue == 1`.)